Pages on /pages of my project working just with live server in VSCode, when i open the pages with a browser whitout live they dont work
I have a problem in my project which is the following: I always run the html with the live server plugin in VSCode to facilitate my development. However, I noticed that when I have the plugin turned off, only the index.html page works and the other pages that are in a folder called pages do not have their CSS applied.
With live server active:
Login page correctly working
With live server deactivated and login page open in browser:
Login page dont working
My project folders structure:
project folders structure
Pages code

index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/forms.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/footer.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/header.css" />
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="assets/images/favicon.svg"
    />
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>GoLearn | Plataforma de estudos</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <a href="#home" class="logoLink">
        <img class="logo" src="assets/images/logo.svg" alt="GoLearn" />
      </a>
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav-links">
          <li><a href="index.html#about-us">Sobre</a></li>
          <li><a href="index.html#contact">Contato</a></li>
          <li><a href="pages/devs.html">Desenvolvedores</a></li>
        </ul>
      </nav>
      <nav>
        <a href="pages/login.html" class="login-btn">LOGIN</a>
        <a href="pages/signup.html" class="signup-btn">CRIAR CONTA</a>
      </nav>
    </header>

    <section class="home" id="home">
      <div class="home-text">
        <h2 class="title">
          CONCENTRE-SE NO <span>APRENDIZADO</span>,<br />
          A<span> ORGANIZAÇÃO</span> É POR NOSSA CONTA!
        </h2>
        <p>
          Adeus à bagunça e à complexidade das plataformas convencionais das Big
          Techs.<br />
          Com a GoLearn, organização é a palavra-chave.
        </p>
        <a href="#about-us" class="about-btn">SAIBA MAIS</a>
        <a href="pages/signup.html" class="meet-btn">CONHEÇA A PLATAFORMA</a>
      </div>
      <div class="home-img">
        <img src="assets/images/mockup.svg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="about-us" id="about-us">
      <div class="about-text">
        <h2 class="title">SOBRE <span>NÓS</span></h2>
        <p>
          A <span>GoLearn</span> é uma plataforma de estudos inovadora projetada
          para proporcionar
          <span>organização, praticidade e eficiência</span> aos alunos e
          professores. Ao se registrar como aluno de uma instituição, os
          usuários têm acesso a todo o conteúdo compartilhado por seus colegas e
          professores. Nossa plataforma apresenta uma interface
          <span>intuitiva</span>, com ícones que direcionam para materiais,
          vídeo aulas, listas de tarefas e atividades extras. Todos os conteúdos
          são submetidos a uma verificação para garantir sua
          <span>qualidade e relevância</span>. Com a GoLearn, estudar e
          colaborar nunca foi tão <span>simples e eficaz</span>.
        </p>
        <a href="pages/signup.html" class="meet-btn">CONHEÇA A PLATAFORMA</a>
      </div>
      <div class="about-img">
        <img src="assets/images/about.svg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="for-teacher">
      <div class="teacher-text">
        <h2 class="title">PARA <span>PROFESSORES</span></h2>
        <p>
          A <span>GoLearn</span> não é apenas para estudantes buscando
          organização; é uma ferramenta
          <span>revolucionária para professores</span> que desejam levar seu
          ensino para o próximo nível. Com a nossa plataforma
          <span>intuitiva</span>, você terá acesso a uma gama de recursos,
          projetados para otimizar seu tempo e aprimorar a experiência de
          aprendizado dos seus alunos.
        </p>
        <a href="pages/signup.html" class="meet-btn">CONHEÇA A PLATAFORMA</a>
      </div>
      <div class="teacher-img">
        <img src="assets/images/teacher.svg" alt="" />
      </div>
    </section>

    <section class="contact" id="contact">
      <div class="contact-text">
        <h2 class="title">ENTRE EM <span>CONTATO</span></h2>
        <p>
          Entre em contato conosco para sanar dúvidas, discutir interesses e
          oportunidades de parceria. Estamos abertos para sugestões ou apenas
          para ter uma conversa.
        </p>
        <div class="social-icons">
          <a href="#" class="socialIcon"><i class="bx bxl-facebook"></i></a>
          <a href="#" class="socialIcon"><i class="bx bxl-twitter"></i></a>
          <a href="#" class="socialIcon"><i class="bx bxl-instagram"></i></a>
          <a href="#" class="socialIcon"><i class="bx bxl-linkedin"></i></a>
          <a href="#" class="socialIcon"><i class="bx bxl-github"></i></a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <form action="" class="contact-form">
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <label for="nome">Nome completo</label>
          <input
            id="nome"
            type="text"
            name="nome"
            placeholder="Digite seu nome completo"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <div class="label-wrapper">
            <label for="email">E-mail</label>
          </div>
          <input
            id="email"
            type="email"
            name="email"
            placeholder="Digite seu email"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <div class="label-wrapper">
            <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
          </div>
          <input
            id="telefone"
            type="tel"
            name="telefone"
            placeholder="Digite seu telefone"
          />
        </div>
        <div class="input-wrapper">
          <div class="label-wrapper">
            <label for="textarea">Mensagem</label>
          </div>
          <textarea
            name="textarea"
            id="textarea"
            placeholder="Escreva sua mensagem"
            maxlength="500"
            oninput="counter()"
            onfocus="showCounter()"
            onblur="hideCounter()"
          ></textarea>
          <div id="contador"></div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
      </form>
    </section>

    <div class="copy">
      <h3>© 2024 GoLearn</h3>
    </div>
  </body>
  <script src="js/char-counter.js"></script>
</html>

login.html:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/forms.css" />
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="/assets/images/favicon.svg"
    />
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>GoLearn | Entrar</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page" class="flex">
      <div>
        <a href="/index.html#home"
          ><img src="/assets/images/logo.svg" alt=""
        /></a>
        <main class="main-login">
          <div class="headline"><h1>Acesse a plataforma</h1></div>
          <p>
            Faça login ou registre-se para começar a estudar com a GoLearn ainda
            hoje.
          </p>
          <form action="">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <label for="email">E-mail</label>
              <input
                id="email"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <div class="label-wrapper">
                <label for="senha">Senha</label>
                <a href="account-recover.html">Esqueceu a senha?</a>
              </div>
              <input
                id="senha"
                type="password"
                name="senha"
                placeholder="Digite sua senha"
                required
              />
              <i
                onclick="togglePassword()"
                class="eye show show-password bx bx-show"
              ></i>
              <i
                onclick="togglePassword()"
                id="hide"
                class="eye hide hide-password bx bx-hide"
              ></i>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Entrar</button>

            <div class="create-account">
              <p>Não possui uma conta? <a href="signup.html">Cadastre-se</a></p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </main>
      </div>
      <img src="/assets/images/banner.svg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <script src="/js/toggle-password.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>


signup.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/global.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/forms.css" />
    <link
      rel="shortcut icon"
      type="image/png"
      href="/assets/images/favicon.svg"
    />
    <link
      href="https://unpkg.com/boxicons@2.1.4/css/boxicons.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <title>GoLearn | Criar conta</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="page" class="flex">
      <div>
        <a href="/index.html#home"
          ><img src="/assets/images/logo.svg" alt=""
        /></a>
        <main class="main-signup">
          <div class="headline"><h1>Cadastre-se</h1></div>
          <p>E comece hoje mesmo a estudar usando a plataforma da GoLearn</p>
          <form action="">
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <label for="nome">Nome completo</label>
              <input
                id="nome"
                type="text"
                name="nome"
                placeholder="Digite seu nome completo"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <label for="telefone">Telefone</label>
              <input
                id="telefone"
                type="tel"
                name="telefone"
                placeholder="Digite seu telefone"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <label for="email">E-mail</label>
              <input
                id="email"
                type="email"
                name="email"
                placeholder="Digite seu e-mail"
                required
              />
            </div>
            <div class="input-wrapper">
              <div class="label-wrapper">
                <label for="senha">Senha</label>
              </div>
              <input
                id="senha"
                type="password"
                name="senha"
                placeholder="Digite sua senha"
                required
              />
              <i
                onclick="togglePassword()"
                class="eye show show-password bx bx-show"
              ></i>
              <i
                onclick="togglePassword()"
                id="hide"
                class="eye hide hide-password bx bx-hide"
              ></i>
            </div>

            <button type="submit">Entrar</button>

            <div class="create-account">
              <p>Já possui uma conta? <a href="login.html">Entrar</a></p>
            </div>
          </form>
        </main>
      </div>
      <img src="/assets/images/banner.svg" alt="" />
    </div>

    <script src="/js/toggle-password.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

I already tried modify the folders structure, modify the href and src of the css files but nothing happen. I tried to put a "." in front of the /styles/global.css or other css file, dont work too.

For the files which are inside pages folder, according to your folder structure, try to use ../ for all href.
For example: href="../styles/global.css"
Because just / may not accessing the file correctly.
